# Pandas prints to screen corrently but saves only some data to csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os, glob
from pandas import Panel
import sqlite3

my_dir = '/home/manish/Desktop/Equity/'
filelist = []
fileList = []
os.chdir(my_dir)

for files in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    p = pd.read_csv(files, names = ['Name', 'Date', 'Open', 'High',
               'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Null'])
    del p['Null']
    print p
    p.to_csv('monthly.csv', sep = ',')

#Even this does not work
#p.to_csv('monthly.csv', sep = ',')
```

My problem is the data is printed correctly to screen, but when I save it to csv, it only saves the data for 1 particular day.

Comment: fix your indentation

Comment: I am working on the monthly data from the National Stock Exchange, for all shares traded daily.

Comment: you read all the files but only save the last one you read in variable `p`.

Comment: @acushner...You are correct. But somehow append or concat is not working

Comment: ok, on your fix, you're now overwriting the same file every time. just do `pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f, ...) for f in files))` and write that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the file once and write as you go, you don't need to store all the data at once which if you had a lot of data may not be possible:

```
os.chdir(my_dir)
glb = glob.iglob('*.txt')

with open("monthly.csv", "w") as f:
    p= pd.read_csv(next(glb), names=['Name', 'Date', 'Open', 'High',
                                  'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Null'])
    del p["Null"]
    p.to_csv(f)
    for files in glb:
        p = pd.read_csv(files, names=['Name', 'Date', 'Open', 'High',
                                      'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Null'])
        del p["Null"]
        p.to_csv(f, sep=',', header=False)
```

You just pass the file object to `p.to_csv` with `header=False` to avoid writing the header multiple times.

If you don't want the Null column, you can pass `usecols=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` instead of deleting the column later:

```
with open("monthly.csv", "w") as f:
    p = pd.read_csv(next(glb), names=['Name', 'Date', 'Open', 'High',
                                      'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'], usecols=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
    p.to_csv(f)
    for files in glb:
        p = pd.read_csv(files, names=['Name', 'Date', 'Open', 'High',
                                      'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'], usecols=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
        p.to_csv(f, sep=',', header=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should do this :

```
my_dir = '/home/manish/Desktop/Equity/'
filelist = []
os.chdir(my_dir)

dfs = []
for files in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    dfs.append(pd.read_csv(files, names = ['Name', 'Date', 'Open', 'High',
               'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Null']))
p = pd.concat(dfs)
del p['Null']
print p
p.to_csv('monthly.csv', sep = ',')
```

Basically I append all the dataframes created from your csv files into a list.
I then use the [pd.concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) function to merge all the rows between each element of the list of dataframes dfs.
Then I remove the 'Null' column.
Instead of print p, you might want to use print p.head() to display only the first 5 elements (default parameter is 5) or p.tail() to display the end.
Finally p.to_csv is exporting the all the merged rows into the file you wanted.

Comment: Excellent. It worked. But please also explain the logic... @Alex

Comment: @Manish, I added some words.