# BeautifulSoup scraped data prints to screen but won't save

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

My code looks like this:

```
import requests #grabs HTML from remote file
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #core scraping module
import csv #prints results to a file
import time #adds delay and avoid overloading host server
from urllib.request import urlopen

# create file to hold scraped data.
artist_csv_file = open('artist_data.csv', 'w')
csv_writer = csv.writer(artist_csv_file)
# nominate header columns for the CSV
csv_writer.writerow(['date_text', 'artist', 'track', 'url'])

# read in a list of URLs to scrap (testing with 3 of 500+ pages)
contents = []
with open('Rage-links.csv','r') as csvf: # Open file in read mode
    urls = csv.reader(csvf)
    for url in urls:
        page = urlopen(url[0]).read()
        rage = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

        # identify page section with artist and track names
        playlist = rage.find('div', class_='comp-rich-text article-text clearfix')   

        # open a CSV file to collect results. And set file's column headers
        artist_csv_file = open('artist_data.csv', 'w')
        csv_writer = csv.writer(artist_csv_file)
        csv_writer.writerow(['date_text', 'artist', 'track', 'url'])

        # capture date from the page
        rage_date = rage.find('div', class_='view-comp-publish-date')
        date_text = rage_date.time.text

        # define the artist and define song title as its sibling
        artist = playlist.find('strong')
        # track = playlist.strong.next_sibling

        # loop through the HTML, write date, artist and track data.
        for artist in playlist.find_all('strong'):
            print(date_text)
            print(artist)
            print(artist.next_sibling)
            print(url)
            time.sleep(.1) # delay scrape for .1 seconds
            csv_writer.writerow([date_text, artist, artist.next_sibling, url])

# close the CSV file
artist_csv_file.close()
```

All of the data prints to screen, but only a portion of it arrives in my CSV file. I'm a novice, so any help appreciated.

I wonder if I'm trying to capture too much data at once as in this post ([Pandas prints to screen corrently but saves only some data to csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32531058/pandas-prints-to-screen-corrently-but-saves-only-some-data-to-csv)) but the explanation is beyond my skill level.

Comment: you're rewriting the file in each loop. delete the opening in the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
artist_csv_file = open('artist_data.csv', 'w')
```

This line overwrites your file with every loop because of the 'w'. Try using 'a' for append then it'll append your results evrey loop at the end of the file.

You probably should initialize the file before the loop to add the column headers, or else it'll probably write a new line of headers every loop.

```
[...]
urls = csv.reader(csvf)

#create/clean artist_data.csv and insert column headers 
with open ('artist_data.csv', 'w+') as artist_csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(artist_csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(['date_text', 'artist', 'track', 'url'])

# this opens the file once for writing the column headers, this first opening with 'w+' makes sure previous content gets cleaned
# if the file is always empty when you run the program you could all in one context manager with 'a+'. 


#now open the csv in append mode and do the scraping
with open('artist_data.csv', 'a') as artist_csv_file:

    csv_writer = csv.writer(artist_csv_file)

    for url in urls:

        [...]
        # these lines should be removed from the loop-body
        artist_csv_file = open('artist_data.csv', 'w')
        csv_writer = csv.writer(artist_csv_file)
        csv_writer.writerow(['date_text', 'artist', 'track', 'url'])
        [...]


# no close statement at the end needed.
```

Hope it helps. Have fun!

Comment: Please don't advice to open and close the output file for each line! Just open it once before the loop in a `with` context manager and let the context manager close it

Comment: I didn't, I just expanded on the given example. But you are right, it's not ideal and I should have done more refactoring, right now it opens a connection every iteration of the loop and closes once at the end.

Comment: Thanks, Bernhard (and Serge). Success! And you were right about duplicated headers.